# Close browser popup in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

I am scraping a page using Selenium, Python. On opening the page one Popup appears. I want to close this popup anyway. I tried as below:

```
url = https://shopping.rochebros.com/shop/categories/37

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver, options=options)
browser.get(url)
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='click' and @id='shopping-selector-parent-process-modal-close-click']").click()
```

I tried a couple of similar posts here but nothing is working with me. below the error, I am getting.

```
 Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@class='click' and @id='shopping-selector-parent-process-modal-close-click']"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The desired element is a `<button>` tag within a *Modal Dialog* so to click on the desired element you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solutions:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://shopping.rochebros.com/shop/categories/37")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='close' and @id='shopping-selector-parent-process-modal-close-click']"))).click()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should wait for the popup to close it:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = "https://shopping.rochebros.com/shop/categories/37"

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver, options=options)
browser.get(url)
wait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "shopping-selector-parent-process-modal-close-click"))).click()
```

If popup might not appear, you can use `try`/`except` to just move on if no popup appeared within 10 seconds:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException 

try:
    wait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "shopping-selector-parent-process-modal-close-click"))).click()
except TimeoutException:
    print("No popup...")
```