# how do I identify if a popup comes up

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I'm making a sneaker bot that simulates a checkout on shoe palace (using air force 1s as an example in this program). Basically what I'm having trouble with is after about 5 seconds after opening the website (it's not a consistent amount of time) I get a popup basically just advertising signing up for their club or whatever and it screws up my code because the button doesn't get pressed so the script terminates. I've tried using time.sleep(5) to hopefully wait for it to popup and then simulating pressing the escape key to close it but it just doesn't work. Is there a way that I can recognize when the popup comes up so I can run a piece of code that closes it immediately? Below I have the code I'm using currently which in an instance where the popup doesn't come up works perfectly. Any help is GREATLY appreciated as I've been stumped with this problem.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
# from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
# keyboard = Controller()
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
#driver.delete_all_cookies()
#open product page (CHANGE THIS)
#driver.get('https://www.shoepalace.com/product/nike/ck7214-100/air-force-1-07-lv8-2-mens-lifestyle-shoe-white-white/')

driver.get('https://www.shoepalace.com/product/nike/ck7214-100/air-force-1-07-lv8-2-mens-lifestyle-shoe-white-white/')

time.sleep(.025)
#secondary size
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/form/div[1]/button[5]")
button.click()
#primary size
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/form/div[1]/button[7]")
button.click()
#add to cart
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/form/div[2]/input")
button.click()
#checkout
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/ul[2]/li[1]")
button.click()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52598793/close-browser-popup-in-selenium-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Close browser popup in Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52598793/close-browser-popup-in-selenium-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method where you should:

1. Identify if the pop-up is displayed
2. Close it if so
3. Wait until pop-up is not displayed

Keep in mind that your code runs line by line, so if you know when the pop up can appear, you can add your method there. If not, based on your code structure is a tricky one because you will need to add it before each action.